# how to remove pagination after the datatable is rendered with pagination

Tags: jquery, datatables, jquery-pagination

My requirement is to have an 'All' button that shows all records of a paginated jquery datatable. Can I manipulate the same datatable, or must I create a new one to display all records without pagination?

Comment: Please read the [faq] and [about] this is not a valid question for SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make use of 
`fnLengthChange` as detailed on the API:

http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api#fnLengthChange

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
    oTable.fnLengthChange( 10000 ); //big limit to show All
} );
```